# Why is my interface method call ignored in a C# generic?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am quite new to C# and I cannot understand the behaviour of a class in my project.

I am using an interface that defines a generic with a type constraint which is another interface.

When I call the generic, I know that a certain method exists on the argument (because of the type constraint), but this method doesn't get executed when I call it.

The only workaround I have so far is to include the method call into the type-specific method overloads.

This may be better explained with the following snippet with an equivalent type structure:

```
public interface ITrickable
{
    void GetRabbitOut();
}

public interface IMagic
{
    void DoTricks<T>(T obj) where T : ITrickable;
}

public class Hat : ITrickable
{
    public void LiftUp() { Console.WriteLine("Lifting up the hat..."); }
    public void GetRabbitOut() { Console.WriteLine("A rabbit came out the hat !"); }
}

public class Box : ITrickable
{
    public void OpenDoubleBottom() { Console.WriteLine("Opening the box..."); }
    public void GetRabbitOut() { Console.WriteLine("A rabbit came out the box !"); }
}

public abstract class Magician : IMagic
{
    public abstract void DoTricks<T>(T obj) where T : ITrickable;
}
```

Now if I call `DoTricks(new Hat()); DoTricks(new Box());` with the class below:

```
public class Houdini : Magician
{
    public override void DoTricks<T>(T obj)
    {
        try {
            DoTricks(obj); }
        catch {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void DoTricks(Hat obj)
    {
        obj.LiftUp();
        obj.GetRabbitOut();
    }

    public void DoTricks(Box obj)
    {
        obj.OpenDoubleBottom();
        obj.GetRabbitOut();
    }
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Lifting up the hat...
A rabbit came out the hat !
Opening the box...
A rabbit came out the box !
```

But if the class is defined as this one below:

```
public class Genesta : Magician
{
    public override void DoTricks<T>(T obj)
    {
        try {
            DoTricks(obj);
            obj.GetRabbitOut(); }  //  <--- This seems to be ignored !?
        catch {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void DoTricks(Hat obj)
    {
        obj.LiftUp();
    }

    public void DoTricks(Box obj)
    {
        obj.OpenDoubleBottom();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Lifting up the hat...
Opening the box...
```

The question is why does `GetRabbitOut` is not called in the second class?

**EDIT**: The calling code is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var houdini = new Houdini();
    var hat = new Hat();
    var box = new Box();

    houdini.DoTricks(hat);
    houdini.DoTricks(box);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It is calling itself, i.e. recursion, not the overload resolution you were looking for.

Comment: @Aybe How do you mean? The program terminates and looking at the output the overload resolution is called.

Comment: I would bet that in fact you're never calling the generic method. To be sure though, we should see the actual calling code.

Comment: Too many overloads for DoTricks().  The compiler will pick the easy one, never the generic one.  The code is in fact not generic, it can only work with a Box or a Hat.

Comment: Try casting to `Magician` or `IMagic` before calling `DoTricks` and please include the calling code as it's very important in this case.  Also put a `Console.WriteLine` into the generic `DoTricks` and you'll see exactly what's happening.  And on another note you shouldn't catch an exception and just replace it with another one like that.

Comment: Well, just as I said. Your calls to `DoTricks` are never resolved to the generic version. Actually if they were, your program would catch a stack overflow exception, since your generic methods are infinitely recursive.

Comment: Thanks it seems that the generic is not called. I thought the compiler would pick the generic first.

Comment: **Learn how to use a debugger.** You should be watching the program flow happen live in the debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: Re: "I thought the compiler would pick the generic first." You thought exactly wrong. C# picks the most *specific* applicable method available, and *generic is the opposite of specific*. If you have methods that take Giraffe, Animal, Object and generic-T, and you pass a Giraffe, then the method that takes the most *specific* thing -- Giraffe -- is called.  Animal, Object, and generics are in decreasing order of specificity.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: Excellent.  Overload resolution is *insanely complicated* in C# when you look at the details but the basic idea is straightforward: a *group of methods* is evaluated to see which are *applicable* to the given arguments. Of the applicable methods, a *unique best method* is chosen if one exists. You now know that "more specific is better than more general", but there is actually an even more important rule: closer is better than farther away. See https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/ for details.

Comment: @EricLippert Ok two things then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice your method calls (I imagine it looked something resembling this):

```
Genesta g = new Genesta();
g.DoTricks(new Hat()); 
g.DoTricks(new Box());
```

Since you call `g.DoTricks(new Hat())` rather than `g.DoTricks<Hat>(new Hat())`, no surprises that the exact method of the Genesta class that is invoked is `DoTricks(T obj)` and not `DoTricks<T>(T obj)`. And when considering the implementation of `DoTricks(T obj)`...

```
public void DoTricks(Hat obj)
{
    obj.LiftUp();
}

public void DoTricks(Box obj)
{
    obj.OpenDoubleBottom();
}
```

The result is actually what you can expect from these methods!

If, however, you would call the generic method like this...

```
g.DoTricks<Hat>(new Hat());
```

You would fall into an infinite recursion, as the method would call itself indefinitely. `DoTricks<T>(T obj)` will always call itself and not one of the specialized overloads `DoTricks(Hat)` or `DoTricks(Box)`, since the compiler cannot know before runtime that T will in fact be either Hat or Box.
By the way, the Houdini class experiences the same effect - it just so happens that its specific `DoTricks(Hat)` and `DoTricks(Box)` methods produce the result that you expected from calling `DoTricks<T>(T obj)`.